# Why the componentDidUpdate is infinitely updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I need to drop a picture, then upload it to the server and update the interface. I have a problem, the lifecycle method componentDidUpdate is beginning to be updated infinitely,  in the condition I indicated to compare this.state with the prevState. (PrevState is undefined, I can not understand why).

I put my code in the sandbox, I hope it will be clear.
https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-smoke-4xxi2

Comment: this.updateAvatarList(); is not found.. Cross origin problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WHY:** This seems like a reference/variable memory address issue.

When you are storing to `itemsList` you are creating a new reference because you are receiving a non-primitive value from the api. JS always operates with references when it comes to non-primitive values. So, your `if (this.state.itemsList !== prevState.itemsList)` will always return `true` because `itemsList` is an array which is non-primitive data set which means JS is not checking it's values but only the references.

I see two solutions atm in this case:

1. Prevent updating the state if the values are same

**OR**

2. Check by values with appropriate checker function in this statement `if (this.state.itemsList !== prevState.itemsList)`

Hope I was able to explain. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct **parameter**. See componentDidUpdate takes `prevProps` as first argument and `prevState` as second.

[image]

Try this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
```

Comment: It will still loop infinitely if the api data length and the state data length is same

Comment: Good catch! I did not notice either. But regardless of that, the code will still hit infinite loop because `itemsList` is an `array` which is a non-premitive dataset :)

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ you should check lengths of array if you can or do deep comparison

Comment: checking lengths will fail as well when the api returns some data that has same length as the state data. Deep comparison is what I have suggested in my answer

Answer (score 0):

prevState is the second argument to componentDidUpdate. Try -

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState) {
    console.log(this.state.itemsList, prevState.itemsList);
    if (this.state.itemsList !== prevState.itemsList) {
      // if you remove the comment from this method, then an infinite update will begin
      //
       this.updateItemList();
    }
  }
```